# Yocto packages not included in image

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am including the [libiio](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/57509/) recipe in my Yocto build, in the recipe there are some packages `PACKAGES =+ "${PN}-iiod ${PN}-tests ${PN}-${PYTHON_PN}"`. The `${PN}-${PYTHON_PN}` package should only be used if a `PACKAGECONFIG` setting is enabled, which I have done in a bbappend file.

I have `IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " libiio"` in my `local.conf`

However, when I run `bitbake core-image-minimal` the resulting image doesn't contain `libiio-iiod` or `libiio-python3` files, It does contain files from the recipe not part of a package though.

I have tried `bitbake -c clean core-image-minimal` and `bitabake -c cleansstate libiio` with no effect.

Some snippets relevant to `libiio` in core-image-minimal's `do-rootfs` log file:

```
---> Package libiio0.cortexa9t2hf_neon 0.23-r0 will be installed
```

```
================================================================================
 Package                     Architecture      Version            Repo     Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 libiio0                     cortexa9t2hf_neon 0.23-r0            oe-repo  49 k
```

```
  Installing       : libiio0-0.23-r0.cortexa9t2hf_neon                  130/131 
  Running scriptlet: libiio0-0.23-r0.cortexa9t2hf_neon                  130/131 
%post(libiio0-0.23-r0.cortexa9t2hf_neon): scriptlet start
%post(libiio0-0.23-r0.cortexa9t2hf_neon): execv(/bin/sh) pid 14247
+ set -e
+ [ x/home/<name>/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/cyclone5-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/rootfs = x ]
%post(libiio0-0.23-r0.cortexa9t2hf_neon): waitpid(14247) rc 14247 status 0
```

```
  Verifying        : libiio0-0.23-r0.cortexa9t2hf_neon                   32/131
```

```
Installed: libiio0-0.23-r0.cortexa9t2hf_neon
```

There are `.rpm` files for `libiio-iiod` and `libiio-python3` with the paths:

`libiio-iiod`

```
build/tmp/work/cyclone5-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo/rpm/cortexa9t2hf_neon/libiio-iiod-0.23-r0.cortexa9t2hf_neon.rpm
```

```
build/tmp/deploy/rpm/cortexa9t2hf_neon/libiio-iiod-0.23-r0.cortexa9t2hf_neon.rpm
```

`libiio-python3`

```
build/tmp/work/cyclone5-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo/rpm/cortexa9t2hf_neon/libiio-python3-0.23-r0.cortexa9t2hf_neon.rpm
```

```
build/tmp/deploy/rpm/cortexa9t2hf_neon/libiio-python3-0.23-r0.cortexa9t2hf_neon.rpm
```

How do I include `libiio-iiod` and `libiio-python3` in the final image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them to `IMAGE_INSTALL`

```
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " libiio libiio-iiod libiio-python3"
```